# During scheduled events in the chats, can we force a notification on room-join?

Tags: feature-request, chat

We already have the notification *before* an event starts in a room, but sometimes you show up in the middle of an event and forget there's an event scheduled. Can we get a notification on room-join if an event is underway, or (as Michael Mrozek suggested) put it prominently on the right hand bar that an event is underway?

Personally I would like both.

Comment: Great idea. I'm not sure about putting more stuff in the side bar, but the "on join" thing sounds good.

Comment: @balpha I think you've got it backwards. You're supposed to like my half of the idea and ignore jcolebrand's half

Comment: [status-mrozek-declined]

Comment: @balpha I figured the on-join would be easiest. You can run a page-loading query or somesuch and then just insert as needed. Anyways, best of luck, please let it be before six weeks ;-) [we pesky moderators and our pesky desires]